# Generating function as Rational Function

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Find the generating function for the sequence ${a_n}$ defined by:

$$a_n=4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}+{n\choose 2}2^n+1$$

for $n\leq 2$ and $a_0=a_1=1$.  Write your answer as a rational function.

Comment: I love to follow orders!

Comment: Any insights of your own?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $n\ge 2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the generating function, write the recurrence as

$$a_n-4 a_{n-1}+4 a_{n-2}=n(n-1)2^{n-1}+1$$

Multiply both sides by $x^n$ and sun from $n=2$ on:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (a_n-4 a_{n-1}+4 a_{n-2}) x^n = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)2^{n-1} x^n + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x^n$$

Define the generating function as

$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$$

We can manipulate the left hand side to produce $g$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n - (a_0-a_1x ) - 4 x \left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n - a_0\right ) + 4 x^2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n \\= (1-4 x+4 x^2)g(x) - (1+x) + 4 x$$

On the RHS, we note that

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)2^{n-1} x^n &= \frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)2^n x^{n-2} \\ &= \frac{x^2}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{1}{1-2 x}\end{align}$$

Also

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}-(1+x)$$

Putting this all together:

$$(1-4 x+4 x^2)g(x) - (1+x) + 4 x = \frac{4 x^2}{(1-2 x)^3} + \frac{1}{1-x} - (1+x)$$

With some algebra, we get the rational function sought:

$$g(x) = \frac{1-10 x+44 x^2-84 x^3+80 x^4-32 x^5}{(1-x)(1-2 x)^3 (1-4 x+4 x^2)}$$

The first several terms in the series expansion for this function are

$$g(x) = 1+x+5 x^2+41 x^3+241 x^4+1121 x^5+4481 x^6+16129
   x^7+53761 x^8+168961 x^9+506881
   x^{10}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$

I leave it to the reader to compare the coefficients to the terms generated in the original recurrence.

Comment: I can manipulate the first one,$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$  fairly easily, but in the second and third summation where did the $x$ and $x^2$ come from? Does that have to do with how you handled the $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$ terms?